# Java 17 and java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Entity not managed

Tags: java, spring, jpa, junit, entitymanager

I have the following test, where foo is retrieved in current transaction, updated in new transaction and refreshed in current transaction. I'm using Spring Boot and Spring Data JPA with JUnit 4.

```
// Test case of @SpringBootTest
@Test
@Transactional
public void testHandleFoo() {
    Foo foo = fooRepository.save(Foo.builder().build());
    sut.handleFoo(foo);
    verify(...);
}

// Service A
@Transactional
public void handleFoo(Foo foo) {
    service.updateFooInNewTransaction(foo.getId()); // REQUIRES_NEW propagation
    entityManager.refresh(foo); // Throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Entity not managed
}

// Service B
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
private updateFooInNewTransaction(long id) {
    fooRepository.getById(id).setValue(...);
}
```

With Java 8 the test work fine, but Java 17 gives the following error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Entity not managed

    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireRefresh(SessionImpl.java:1245)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.refresh(SessionImpl.java:1202)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
```

Why `refresh` method doesn't work with Java 17?

Comment: Which Spring Boot version and please add your pom or build file.

Comment: Does it help if you "reattach" the entity, again? `Foo mergedFoo = entityManager.merge(foo); entityManager.refresh(mergedFoo);`
It may be possible that your used version of Spring/Hibernate is not compatible with Java 17.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring data Jpa Entity not managed Exception when calling refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44554783/spring-data-jpa-entity-not-managed-exception-when-calling-refresh)